# Why is the dismiss() animation not playing?

Tags: swift

I have an onboarding flow for my app held in WelcomeViewController. I introduce that code in the SceneDelegate as shown:

```
var window: UIWindow?
    
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let winScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        window = UIWindow(windowScene: winScene)
        
        if Core.shared.isNewUser() {
            let welcomeViewCon = WelcomeViewCon()
            welcomeViewCon.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            window?.rootViewController = welcomeViewCon
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        } else {
            // Tab Bar
            Core.shared.setIsNewUser()
            let tabBarCon = TabBarController()

            window?.rootViewController = tabBarCon
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
```

After the onboarding flow is complete, I dismiss the WelcomeViewController like this:

```
        guard button.tag < 4 else {
            // dismiss
            Core.shared.setIsNotNewUser()
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                let tabBarCon = TabBarController()
                let sceneDelegate = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first!.delegate as! SceneDelegate
                sceneDelegate.window?.rootViewController = tabBarCon
            })
            return
        }
```

This code does work, but the dismiss animation is not displaying. Can anyone please advise on how to get the dismiss animation to play?

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the `modalPresentationStyle` of your `WelcomeViewCon` to `. fullScreen`, but then you're setting it to be the root view controller. This most likely is resulting in the modal presentation view to be ignored and it is just presented as a regular view controller.

When you call dismiss, there's nothing to dismiss from, because it's not being presented modally in front of another controller. So, the completion fires, which then removes the view from the hierarchy completely, which functionally dismisses it).

One way to solve this would be to make a blank UIViewController and set it to the root view and then present your `WelcomeViewCon` on top of it -- then you would at least get the animation. It seems like what you may actually want, though, is to have the `TabBarController` as the root view controller and present the `WelcomeViewCon` on top of it. Then, in your dismiss code, you could also ditch the code that resets the window's root view.

Comment: Yes, you're right, the `TabBarCon` is the base of the main app and the `WelcomeViewCon` should dismiss to it. I had tried presenting the `WelcomeViewCon` from the `TabBarCon` but I was getting the error "attempting to present X on Y whose view is not in the window hierarchy!" and the view wasn't displaying at all. How would I get around that error?

Comment: Make your tab bar, set it to the root view controller, and call your `window?.makeKeyAndVisible()`. Then, try to create the `WelcomeViewCon` and present it on top (after everything is visible). If it still complains (which it probably will not at this point), you could wrap the `WelcomeViewCon` in a `DispatchQueue.main.async { }` to present it on the next run loop.

Comment: But that's the thing, I don't want to present the `WelcomeViewCon` after the main app is already visible. I want the onboarding flow to precede the `TabBarCon`, so `TabBarCon` is not shown until `WelcomeViewCon` dismisses to it.

Comment: Well, then I would suggest my first option (presenting over a blank view controller) would be the easiest option. Second option would be to have some sort of state variable that you keep track of where the tab controller doesn't actually load any data until the onboarding happens. Then, you could still present your `WelcomeViewCon` on top, but it would have empty data first, and then on dismiss, you could load the data.